# IIS and ISA Server 2006 on the same machine

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, site-to-site-vpn, isa-server

I've got quite a hairy problem.

I need to create a site-to-site VPN between a dedicated server (which hosts several websites) and a network (from a client) in order to use their webservices (and no, they aren't willing to publicly publish their websevices).

Therefore, the first solution I thought I could use is to install ISA Server on my dedicated server and publish its websites via it and, at the same time, be able to create the VPN site-to-site. The VPN worked just fine. However, even after changing websites to listen to an alternative port (like, 81), I can't get them to be published via ISA Server 2006.

Is there a guide or something I can relate to to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with ISA, but one thing I remember (other than this being an evil scenario) was to make sure IIS is binding to an IP address that is internal to your ISA.

There are a ton of useful articles on [**isaserver.org**](http://isaserver.org) and also on [**windowssecurity.com**](http://windowssecurity.com), I'm sure that this would be mentioned over there.  I'll see if I can find something useful for you.